# Python thread stuck while another thread waiting for user input

Tags: python-2.7, python-multithreading, raw-input

I am using python 2.7, with the module threading. Now I am having a countdown of 24 hours which is one thread, the other thread is taking user input using raw input.
When my program run, the countdown thread is waiting for the user input to be inserted, and only then the countdown continues. At the first place my reason of using threading is to achieve both the threads run at the same time. I just can't understand why would one thread wait for the input of another one? And how to fix that?
Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

OK so i figured out that threading module is not actually apply parallel running of threads because of some mechanism called GIL. My solution is using multi processing instead. It works fine. Hope it helped someone.

Comment: please mark this answer as Accepted (green check mark) if the question has been answered

Comment: Thank you for your attention. Is it ok now?